# How to set visibility of a point in a Highcharts series?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a stacked column chart in Highcharts with several categories. In the xAxis categories, I just want to show 'Delhi', 'Jammu & Kashmir', 'Madhya Pradesh', 'Maharashtra', 'West Bengal' and 'Kerala' when the chart is loaded for the first time. The user can then select other categories (like 'Andhra Pradesh' by clicking a button). So I want that all categories other than the initial categories to be invisible. 
Here is a snippet of the object that I've created. Data is getting displayed for all categories, irrespective of their visibility.
Where am I going wrong?

```
var revenueComposition = [{
name: 'Grants in Aid',
data: [{
    name: 'Delhi',
    y:6.4
    }, {
    name: 'Jammu & Kashmir',    
    y:57
    }, {
    name: 'Kerala',
    y: 12
    }, {
    name: 'Madhya Pradesh',
    y: 18.7
    }, {
    name: 'Maharashtra',
    y: 13.5
    }, {
    name: 'West Bengal',
    y: 24.6}, {
    name: 'Andhra Pradesh',
    y: 29.9,
    visible: false 
    }, {
        name: 'Bihar',
            y: 26.9,
            visible: false 
    }, {
        name: 'Chhattisgarh',
        y: 21.3,
        visible: false 
    }, {
        name: 'Gujarat',
        y: 11.9,
        visible: false 
    }, {
        name: 'Haryana',
        y: 10.2,
        visible: false 
    }, {
        name: 'Karnataka',
        y: 11.1,
        visible: false 
    }, {
        name: 'Odisha',
        y: 23.8,
        visible: false 
    }, {
        name: 'Punjab',
        y: 11.1,
        visible: false 

    }, {
        name: 'Rajasthan',
        y: 18.3,
        visible: false 
    }, {
        name: 'Telangana',
        y: 11.2,
        visible: false 
    }, {
        name: 'Uttar Pradesh',
        y: null,
        visible: false 
    }],
    },
```

Comment: exactly what you want, official example is http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked/ and the data you are using differs from official  example. Add verified example which shows the issue.

Comment: @Deep3015, I am able to create a stacked chart, I just want to make some points in series hidden. The chart should show only certain categories when loaded for the first time. Like in the example you have given, Grapes and Bananas should be hidden, the user can select them using a button

Comment: check this  http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/oL128n9u/1/

Comment: yeah this works somewhat, how can i toggle this button? to show/hide categories?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/oL128n9u/20/